# How can I make a shadow for a text of Label in python code (kivy)?

Tags: python, kivy

There is example from @Tshirtman in GitHub.
https://gist.github.com/tshirtman/5651140
Thanks for it, but I don't understand this two command in kv file:

```
        size: root.texture_size
        texture: root.texture
```

What does it mean root in this case?
And how can I rewrite class ShadowLabel in python?

Comment: The `root` refers to the root of the rule in which that line appears, so it refers to the `ShadowLabel` instance.  The class is written in python. It is only the display that is written in `kv`, as are most of the widgets in kivy.

Comment: Ok. The root refers to the ShadowLabel. What does self refer to? Canvas?

Comment: In this case, self and root refer to the same thing.